# Concrete 5 Remote SQL

Tags: mysql, cpanel, concrete5

I am wanting to do a Remote MySQL with 2 servers, server 1 holding the database & server 2 holding the website & images etc.

Now they both run on cPanel, both with the same server build.

Now as far as I know the last part of the config which I currently have as this;

```
<?php
define('DB_SERVER', '185.52.24.69');
define('DB_USERNAME', '***');
define('DB_PASSWORD', '****');
define('DB_DATABASE', '***');
```

What do I put for the dbserver, obviously when I first installed it, the server was on localhost but now it must be changed, I have tried the direct url, IP, IP with 3306 at the end. None work.

I am getting this error;
Unable to connect to database.
A database error occurred while processing this request.

Has anyone done something like this who could advise me on the next step of problem solving?
Thanks
Ross

Comment: Why would you want to store on 2 different servers? For the DB server, you will want to use the IP address where the Concrete5 is installed rather than the images etc

Comment: 2 servers are one of our clients wants the website on their hosting, but doesn't want to pay the price (but pays us on a monthly basis) so I am willing for him to have the website, but the db he will not have. - I have fixed this though :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to know that Concrete5 pre 5.7 is notoriously slow when running on a remote db.
I don't know about new version